# What should I do if I want to cover only human objects in Mask R-CNN?

Tags: python, masking

I am currently running Mask R-CNN. I want to recognize only human objects and then cover only human objects.

So I tried to erase 80 objects that were learned in the coco file, but they didn't work correctly. I tried using the index number of a person object, but it didn't work.

```
class_names = [
    'BG', 'person',
    'bicycle', 'car', 'motorcycle', 'airplane',
    'bus', 'train', 'truck', 'boat', 'traffic light',
    'fire hydrant', 'stop sign', 'parking meter', 'bench', 'bird',
    'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'sheep', 'cow', 'elephant', 'bear',
    'zebra', 'giraffe', 'backpack', 'umbrella', 'handbag', 'tie',
    'suitcase', 'frisbee', 'skis', 'snowboard', 'sports ball',
    'kite', 'baseball bat', 'baseball glove', 'skateboard',
    'surfboard', 'tennis racket', 'bottle', 'wine glass', 'cup',
    'fork', 'knife', 'spoon', 'bowl', 'banana', 'apple',
    'sandwich', 'orange', 'broccoli', 'carrot', 'hot dog', 'pizza',
    'donut', 'cake', 'chair', 'couch', 'potted plant', 'bed',
    'dining table', 'toilet', 'tv', 'laptop', 'mouse', 'remote',
    'keyboard', 'cell phone', 'microwave', 'oven', 'toaster',
    'sink', 'refrigerator', 'book', 'clock', 'vase', 'scissors',
    'teddy bear', 'hair drier', 'toothbrush'
]


 def apply_mask(image, mask, color, alpha=1):    #alpha값 0.5->1
    """apply mask to image"""
    for n, c in enumerate(color):
          image[:, :, n] = np.where(
                mask == 1,
               image[:, :, n] *(1 - alpha) + alpha * c,
               image[:, :, n]
            )

    return image
```

Even if I modify the code, the program continues to recognize objects that are not human objects.